# Finding the square root $s$ of 1293 modulo 3337.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $3337 = 47 \cdot 71$, how do you find the square root $s$ of $1293 \pmod { 3337}$ (where $0 < s < 3337$).

I understand that $m = 3337 = p \cdot q$ and  $p=47$ and $q=71$, but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Microhint: Find the square root mod 47 and mod 71, then apply the Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a neat way to find square roots for $3 \pmod 4$ primes. If we want the solution for $x^2 \equiv c \pmod p$, then by Fermat, $c \cdot c^{(p-1)/2} \equiv c \equiv (c^{(p+1)/4})^2$ so the solutions are $\pm c^{(p+1)/4}$. No such easy way exists for $1 \pmod 4$ primes I think.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $\displaystyle x^2\equiv1293\pmod{47\cdot71}\implies x^2\equiv1293\pmod{47}\equiv24$

Now by trial, $\displaystyle(\pm2)^2\equiv4\pmod{47}, (\pm10)^2\equiv6\pmod{47}$

So, $\displaystyle(\pm2\cdot10)^2\equiv4\cdot6=24\implies x\equiv\pm20\pmod{47}\ \ \ \ (1)$

Similarly,  $\displaystyle x^2\equiv1293\pmod{47\cdot71}\implies x^2\equiv1293\pmod{71}\equiv15$

$\displaystyle x^2\equiv15\pmod{71}\equiv15+3\cdot71=228$

Setting $x=2y\implies y^2\equiv57\equiv57+71=128=2^7$

Setting $y=8z\implies z^2\equiv2\pmod{71}\equiv2+2\cdot71=12^2\implies z\equiv\pm12$

$x=2y=2(8z)=16(\pm12)=\pm192\equiv\pm50\pmod{71}\  \ \ \ (2)$

Then apply [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) on $(1),(2)$ to find all the four solutions

Comment: So to editorialize, your method of calculating the root is to add multiples of  the modulus until a square factor appears, then "divide" by that factor and continue the same again.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By the Chinese Remainder Theorem,  $$x^2 \equiv 1293 \mod 3337\\ \iff\\ x^2 \equiv 1293 \mod 47\ \ \text{ and }x^2\ \ \equiv 1293 \mod 71$$

You can then solve these slightly easier equations and piece things back together with the Chinese Remainder Theorem again.

**Warning:** each of these equations (mod $47$ and $71$) has two solutions, so overall you will have $4$ solutions. (This is because $3337$ is not prime, and hence $\mathbb Z / (3337\mathbb Z)$ is not an integral domain.)

---

In general, with this kind of question, the easiest solution will often be to break the problem up into smaller, easily solvable pieces using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and then piece things back together.

Comment: Do you have a systematic method of calculating the roots for a prime modulus ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus as far as I'm aware there is no general method that could be employed by hand aside from reducing the problem as far as possible and brute-forcing it. There are some computationally efficient algorithms, but I feel they would be overkill for a question like this.

Comment: What about using a primitive root ? I guess the difficulty is finding it and checking it.

Comment: That and also if $g$ is a primitive root, you'd still have to solve $g^k \equiv 1293 \mod n$ and I'm not sure how efficient that would be. In terms of algorithms there is the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm (can't get the wikipedia link to work!! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli–Shanks_algorithm) but it would probably be overkill here.

Comment: $g^\frac{p-1}2$ will just be $-1$ - doesn't help too much. You need $\pm g^k$ where $g^{2k} \equiv 1293$. But I don't see how calculating that is going to be much better than just trying $\frac{p-1}{2}$ possible values.

Comment: Oh right, yes you do have to solve the equation you gave, I was just confused in my last comment.